# Changing background of drawable instance in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, drawable

I have a drawable resource `drawable/badge.xml` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

...and is used inside a layout file `layout/badge.xml` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/badge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside a BaseExpandableListAdapters `getChildView` method there is this code:

```
...
LinearLayout badgeContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.badge_container);
for (String property : properties) {

    RelativeLayout badge = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.badge, badgeContainer, false);

    badge.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));

    ((TextView) badge.findViewById(R.id.badge_text)).setText(course.property);
    badge.findViewById(R.id.badge).getBackground().setColorFilter(getColorResourceByProperty(property), PorterDuff.Mode.DST);

    badgeContainer.addView(badge);
}
...
```

So what I'm trying to do is change the background color of the drawable badge for each `property`, but this code still yields in all badges to have a black background. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried many other PorterDuff modes without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting some more I got it working like this:

`drawable/circle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

</shape>
```

`layout/badge.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/badge_text"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and inside the adapter:

```
LinearLayout badgeContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.badge_container);
for (int i = 0; i < course.properties.length; i++) {

    TextView badge = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.badge, badgeContainer, false);
    badge.setText(course.properties[i]);
    int colorID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("property_" + course.properties[i], "color", context.getPackageName());
    badge.getBackground().setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(colorID), Mode.MULTIPLY);

    badgeContainer.addView(badge);
}
```